# Do angular provide any way to isolate the service layer?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, web-services, rest

I'm using AngularJs In my front-end, And I'm consuming a RESTful service.
to consume the service I have to compose send request payload as json, and will get a response as json.

And I will have some Angular models which are bind with form inputs, directives, services etc......

Do angular provide any good way to isolate the service layer from front-end design or should we implement ourself, or should I proceed with tight coupling the front end with service ?

Comment: In ng-resource there are transformResponse/transformRequest

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not necessary at all. Format of JSON request payload, response of web-services and angular models, all three can have the different schema. You just need to write your parser/adapter to convert one kind of json to other.

Comment: Can you suggest me any good pattern to write the parsers ?
I'm planing to write the parsers in the angular service that consumes the rest and act as a service endpoint.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no specific way of writing parsers. Mostly parsers are simply written as data mapping between two objects like parsed.a = toBeParsed.b